# Why does Node.js Net library not throw proper exception for ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js

### Environment:

**Node.js Version:** v8.12.0

**V8:** 6.2.414.66

**OS:** MacOS

**Scope (install, code, runtime, meta, other?):** Serving Node using nginx and Phusion Passenger

**Module (and version) (if relevant):** net

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:618:25)
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  fatal: true
```

Node is kept throwing above error. However, I'm trying to understand if this error is due to network connectivity between the server where nodejs api and other data sources such as MySQL, Redis

From the above error, I do see its a network issue, however, that does not reveal much information about the error.
Been wondering if there are ways to debug this issue.

Comment: ECONNRESET is an OS error code meaning the server or client at the far end of a TCP/IP connection abruptly disconnected.  You did not mention what connections your program uses, so it's hard to help you.  Did you force-quit something to cause this?

Comment: @O.Jones main connections are mysql and redis that they live in their respective servers

Comment: The core Node API is not based around exceptions, but errors provided via callbacks. In what context are you seeing this? Do you have some code that can reproduce it?

Comment: @tadman Its quite hard to reproduce the issues. Since the exception does not reveal much it's hard to know the cause of the exception. Clearly, the exception is a network connectivity issue (net.js:618:25), but difficult to reproduce if its caused by which one of the external servers (MySQL or Redis) causing the issue .

Comment: Without a stack trace there's really no way to tell what's causing this. It could be anything that makes a connection to anything, which isn't really going to narrow things down to something actionable.

Comment: @tadman I absolutely agree with you. Node exception error doesn't reveal which connection is causing the issue. I will give try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sometimes you need to cross-reference this with logs from the various things that code is connecting to, or even use a tool like [`tcpdump`](https://www.tcpdump.org) to capture network traffic and find out which connection failed.

Comment: Important note: stop using Node 8. It went out of any and all support on January 1st, you _really_ want to be on Node 10 at the very least, but you really want to be on 12. See https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/ for how long you can expect to safely be on specific Node versions. Also note that "Darwin" is a platform architecture, not a MacOS version (that's like saying you're using windows x64 "win32"). current MacOS versions take the form of a name and a 10.x,y version (easily found in "about this mac").

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the suggestion. That helps.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes, very good point. I'm already considering to switch to Node 10. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Upgrade first and see if the problem still exists. There's a non-zero chance it no longer does.

Comment: Node's on v13.9 now, so if you're going to upgrade, upgrade as much as you can in one shot. [Node v10 is losing support in 2021](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/). v12 might make sense if you want to stick with a deployment for a while, or v13 if you're intending to upgrade later.

Comment: No need to upgrade a production system to a non-LTS version of Node. However, there _is_ a need to show your actual [mcve] because right now all people can do is guess at the problem, instead of just reproduce it.